# solve in positive integers sum of squares of sines equation

Tags: number-theory, contest-math, cyclotomic-polynomials

Find all positive integer triples $(l,m,n)$ such that $\sin^2\frac{\pi}{n}+\sin^2\frac{\pi}{m}=\sin^2\frac{\pi}{l}$.

I have found the solutions $(m,m,1)$ for any $m\in\mathbb{Z}^+$, and also $(2,3,6),(2,6,3),(2,4,4),(4,6,6)$. It seems like these are the only ones (unless I missed a few other simple solutions), but I'm not sure how to prove it.

The article I found this problem was on cyclotomic polynomials, and the hint for this problem was to rewrite the equation in something that relates to cyclotomic polynomials, so that is what I tried to do:

Write the equation as $1-\cos^2\frac{\pi}{n}+1-\cos^2\frac{\pi}{m}=1-\cos^2\frac{\pi}{l}\rightarrow \cos^2\frac{\pi}{n}+\cos^2\frac{\pi}{m}=1+\cos^2\frac{\pi}{l}$. Now use $\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos2x}{2}$ to rewrite the equation as $\cos\frac{2\pi}{l}+1=\cos\frac{2\pi}{m}+\cos\frac{2\pi}{n}$. Let $\omega_x=e^{i\frac{2\pi}{x}}$ for $x\in\mathbb{Z}^+$. Then $\frac{\omega_l+\overline{\omega_l}}{2}=\frac{\omega_m+\overline{\omega_m}}{2}+\frac{\omega_n+\overline{\omega_n}}{2}-1$. I do not know how to proceed from here.

Any ideas? A solution with cyclotomic polynomials would be nice!

Comment: Could you provide a link to and/or citation of the article? Not that the question _needs it_, but it would provide some additional context.

Comment: BTW, $\cos^2x=\frac{1+\cos(2x)}{2}$, not as stated.

Comment: @Galc127 Thanks, I've fixed it now. Though that did not affect by end result since I used the right equation.

Comment: This question is related to spherical trigonometry and to sphere tessellation by triangles. See theorem 3 in (http://mathcs.slu.edu/history-of-math/images/history/b/b3/AMM-right-right-triangle-sphere.pdf) . A powerpoint presentation can be found in (http://www.facstaff.bucknell.edu/ed012/bowdoin_13apr10.pdf). See the EXCELLENT site (http://www.revolvy.com/main/index.php?s=Spherical%20trigonometry) Have a look also at sphere tesselations that you can "make" using http://math.exeter.edu/rparris/wgsthelp.html

Comment: @Semiclassical Here is the article: http://lessol.w.staszic.waw.pl/pdfy/h.pdf

Comment: A connection to cyclotomic polynomials:
Let $N:=lcm(n,m,l)$. Then $w_N^{\bar n}=w_n$ and $w_N^{N-\bar n}=\overline{w_n}$,
where $\bar n:= N/n$.
Similarly  $w_N^{\bar m}=w_m$, $w_N^{N-\bar m}=\overline{w_m}$,  $w_N^{\bar l}=w_l$ and $w_N^{N-\bar l}=\overline{w_l}$, where $\bar l:=N/l$ and  $\bar m:=N/m$. 

Then $w_N$ satisfies the equality $P(w_N)=0$, where
$$
P(x)=x^{\bar n}+x^{N-\bar n}+x^{\bar m}+x^{N-\bar m}-x^{\bar l}-x^{N-\bar l}-2.
$$
Hence the cyclotomic polynomial $\Phi_N(x)$ divides $P(x)$.

Comment: You missed the solutions $(3,4,6), (3,6,4), (5,6,10), (5,10,6)$.